# Add custom headers for CsvMapper and CsvSchema

Tags: java, spring, rest, csv

I have the following piece of Java/Spring code which sends the user a CSV file in a Rest Controller.

try{
OutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();

```
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper
                .schemaFor(TestForCsv.class)
                .withHeader();

        csvMapper.addMixIn(Test.class, TestForCsv.class);

        Test[] reportData = new ObjectMapper().readValue(tstDao.testmethod(locId), Test[].class);

        csvMapper.writerFor(Test[].class)
                .with(csvSchema)
                .writeValue(outs, reportData);


        outs.flush();
        outs.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This works well and generates a CSV with the fields from my database. For ex, the Test object has a keyId field in the database and the csv is created as expected with that field name but I would like to rename the keyId to something like "Key ID". I am not sure if I can use the .withHeader() method to customize CSV field/header names?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the `@JsonProperty` annotation on `TestForCsv`

```java
@JsonProperty("Key ID")
private Long keyId;
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but don't the field names have to match in TestForCsv and Test? and the field inside Test need to map the DB field I believe.